# Why Won't A PHP Page Load When Using Mobile Network?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

This belongs to one of those "weird or what" situations.   I have built an order processing system using codeigniter ( a very light weight MVC php framework).  Amongst many things it generates invoices for orders. It runs faultlessly on a hard wire internet connection.

However, if I run my invoices page over a mobile 3G  connection the invoices page fails to display ***only when there are 5 or more line items on the page***. The error message I get back is:

> requested content www.mysite/index.php/invoices cannot be processed due to error while parsing reply

However if there are 4 items or less, it runs fine ..... weird or what ??

I have Googled everything and can find only scant references to this error message.

Does anyone have the vaguest idea what could be going wrong ?  Or perhaps where else I can Google ?

Many Many Thanks !

Comment: please accept you past questions, then you should put some code you are using for find out the main problem !

Comment: Just guessing: is the reply with 5 items actually valid HTML?

Comment: @Ispuk I could add code .. sure, but, as it is built on an MVC framwork, I would have to add view + model + controller. Do you really want all that ? Here is the code snippet which generates the HTML:

Comment: What mobile device are you using? Make sure your output is (x)html valid and most devices should run fine.

Comment: @VinceJacobs well should be good for you for help people helpin you

Comment: Can not see how to post all the code.

 Question, if it was invalid HTML would it not fail on not the wired network as well ?

Comment: @john - great idea, now my dumb question: as my html is actually being delivered within a .php file are you saying I should examine all the tags or are  you suggesting that I need to change the doc type within the header ? tks !

Comment: I'd love to accept a specific answer but it is quite unclear how in fact how to do that

Comment: Can you just post a link to the page?  The problem you have could be just about *anything*, and you haven't provided nearly enough information to help us help you.  If you post a link, that might be easier.

Comment: @Brad - point taken, and i would, however, the page is within the admin section of the application and behind a u/n and p/w.  Even posting a link to the demo system would be risky on the open internet. However, I could post some code for the view HTML page. However I don't see how to paste it onto this question.

Comment: @Vince, Click edit on your question, paste the code in, highlight it, and click the code format button.  However, I'm not convinced this is an HTML issue.  It very well could be a connectivity problem, or an issue with some JavaScript.

Comment: @Brad - thanks. I gave it a go, however, the edit feature won't take the whole page of code .. it chops it off 3/4 down. 

I also tested another page on a samsung phone over cell network. That other page was very long .. not xhtml optimised, no mobile css ... and it rendered fine. the problem is not specific to a small form cell phone .. even if you try it with a laptop + 3G stick the page fails. Bummer

Comment: Sounds like network problems to me.